# TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'> even though using latest pytorch version

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I had to create a new pytorch environment in Anaconda, I created my code and it worked fine in my old environment. I then created the new environment with the same version of pytorch and cuda 10.1 (but then updated to cuda 11, same as the old one. WHen i try to run the same code i get the error:

TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>

When trying to apply any transformation to my tensors, for example the following code gives me an error:

```
def randRoll(batch, deg):
rotator = torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation(deg)
batch = rotator(batch)
return batch
```

Nothing has changed and I can't understand why i would get this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

Turns out somehow torchvision 0.2.2 had been installed instead of the latest 0.9.1 (which my other environment used).

This was solved by uninstalling torchvision using

```
conda remove torchvision
```

then installing torchvision using pip (using conda install gave me version 0.2.2)

```
pip install torchvision
```

I also had to reinstall six using pip.